# Python JSON API Print the list inside of a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
import requests
import re
import json
p={
    'collection': 'wisecards',
    'limit':5
    }

g=requests.get("https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?offset=0",params=p)
x=(g.json())
price=[d['sell_orders']['current_price'] for d in x['assets']]
print(price)
```

and I get this error:

```
price=[d['sell_orders']['current_price'] for d in x['assets']]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The JSON data is here: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/izeresurub.py

How can I print the list inside this dictionary?

Using `price=[d['sell_orders'] for d in x['assets']]` print the whole list,but i want just a specific part of it `['current_price']`

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: As you’re discovering, comprehensions can be difficult to debug. Expand it to a for loop then you can print any of the variables as you iterate so you can discover which isn’t a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

`x['assets']` is a list of length 1 that contains a dict.

`x['assets'][0]` accesses the dict within that list.

`x['assets'][0]['sell_orders']` yields yet another list that contains 1 dict

`x['assets'][0]['sell_orders'][0]` accesses the dict in that list (length 42 - all attributes of the sell order)

`x['assets'][0]['sell_orders'][0]['current_price]` gets you what you want.

In the future for troubleshooting, try checking what the type of everything is and using `dir(object)` to check `object`'s attributes

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your code gives me this error:"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" –

Comment: Did this end up working?

Answer (score 1):

The element in the JSON seems to be a list, so iterating over it will yield the items themselves but here ya go

```
import requests
import re
import json
p={
    'collection': 'wisecards',
    'limit':5
    }
g = requests.get("https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?offset=0", params=p).json()
for d in g['assets'][1]['sell_orders']:
    price = d['current_price']
print(price)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your code gives me this error:"TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: huh it does?, that code worked for me and I got the current price